# What is the difference between DEFAULT ((0)) and DEFAULT (0)?? Is there any?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The reason I ask is that I am comparing databases on two SQL 2008 servers.

One scripts the DEFAULTS on a particular table using two (()) and the other with only one ()?

Comment: There is literally no difference apart from one over uses parenthesis.

Comment: *"I am comparing databases on two SQL 2005 servers"* why did you tag 2008 then? (Not that it actually matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default(0)` has one unnecessary set of parenthesis.
`default((0))` has two unnecessary sets of parenthesis.

Here's a demo:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Col0 int default 0,
    Col1 int default (0),
    Col2 int default ((0))
);

INSERT INTO Test DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO Test DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT Id, Col0, Col1, Col2
FROM Test
```

Result:

```
Id  Col0    Col1    Col2
1   0       0       0
2   0       0       0
```

BTW, If you're working with SQL Server 2008 you should seriously consider upgrading your system, as it's out of extended support as of July 2019.
2005 version extended support ended in April 2016, so if you're working with this version you should update, no consideration needed.